# In Android drawing, how do I paint a uniform stroke along a polygon Path?

Tags: android, path, drawing, android-canvas, paint

I have a path that draws a polygon (in this case, a hexagon). I would like to paint the path with a uniform thickness. However, when I set the stroke width to anything other than 0, the diagonal edges are significantly thicker than the horizontal edges.

My question is, how can I configure my paint and path combination to achieve a uniform stroke along the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was encountering occurred because I was drawing my polygon hard against the boundaries of my canvas. Consequently, only half of the stroke was visible on edges draw perpendicular and hard against an edge.

The solution was to introduce an inner margin. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with anti-aliasing.  Try enabling it on the `Paint` object via [`setAntiAlias(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setAntiAlias(boolean)).

If that doesn't work, please post a screenshot of what you're seeing.